# How to launch an Blackberry app on device turn on/switch on

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I did the following but it not work for always.It works if i launch the app manually and then turn off the device and turn on the device my app is launched. But before turning off the device if i switched to  another app then after switch-on the device,"My app is not getting launch".

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor;
import net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

public class MyApp extends UiApplication
{
public static void main(String args[]) {

    if (args.length == 0) 
    {                      
        ApplicationDescriptor current =         ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();             
        current.setPowerOnBehavior(ApplicationDescriptor.POWER_ON);
        ApplicationManager manager = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
        manager.scheduleApplication(current, System.currentTimeMillis() 
        + 2000, true);
    }
    System.out.println("restarted !");
    MyApp app = new MyApp();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public MyApp()
{           
     pushScreen(new MyScreen());
}
```

}

```
Please help..........it's important...and thanks a lot.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not a blackberry expert, but I develop for iOS and Android. The on/off switch or power button is hardly linked to the device, and the action performed when it's pressed is written in the operating system, not in an application, I don't think you'll find an event listener for this button to be pressed, just imagine the security issues it could raise if an app could prevent the phone from turning off (or on ...)

Comment: yes i agree with you but in android we can do it.There should be any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse project, open the `Blackberry_App_Description.xml` file, go to the "Alternate Entry Points" tab, add a new entry to the list, enable its "Auto-run on startup" option, and give it an "Application argument" value of your choosing.  You can then update your `main()` function to look for that value when the app runs:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    if ((args != null) && (args.length > 0) && (args[0].equals("MyValue"))) 
    {                      
        System.out.println("System Startup !");
    }

    MyApp app = new MyApp();
    app.enterEventDispatcher();
}
```

Comment: In what way? It always you to run code at device startup, such as scheduling apps to run. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want that my app get launch on every startup/switchon the device not on reset the device.

Comment: Using an Alternative Entry Point is how you get your app to run at device startup/powerup. That does include OS software reboots. Why do you want to ignore those? Your `setPowerOnBehavior()` code does not work because what you are attempting is not what `setPowerOnBehavior()` is meant for. Setting `POWER_ON` simply means to turn on the device if it is current off when the scheduler runs your app. That is not the same thing as running your app when the device powers up. What EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please solve my problem... i want to get the GPS lat,long and need to display it when device is turn-on each time automatically without manual launch the app.   It's humble request plz solve my problem.

Comment: I already told you what you need to do - create an Alternate Entry Point and set it to autorun at startup. Have you actually tried it yet?

Comment: hello sir, i have tried it , and i am working with the eclipse ide 3.6.2 . but not work, only work on hard-reset.

Answer (score 0):

On android its totally possible. You only have to register a broadcast receiver with the correct filter and add the permission on the manifest.

I think you should not think of this function from the buttons point of view and more on the power on **event** point of view.